# How do I create a sqlite 3 (.sl3) database file?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I have a *.sqlite file... but I need the database in *.sl3 format?
What software/tool can I us to create that?

What are the steps?

This is to be used in an iPhone app. Original developer used an .sl3 file, now that I have updated the DB - I can't seem to export/generate a .sl3 file

I have tried just changing the extension - all the way to inserting the *.sqlite file in XCode and pointing the app delegates to the new DB file format... doesn't work.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in the Terminal using the sqlite3 tool? If so did you experience any errors?

Comment: I always thought you could just type SQL files in a text editor... Aren't they just supposed to be text that the database runs as queries?

Comment: I understood he has a SQLite database file, not a SQL script file.
@BC could you please clarify?

Comment: @BC What do you get when you open a terminal and run: file yourfile.sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the file.  SQLite doesn't care about file extensions.  You could call it "mydatabase.froggy" if you want.

Update: Reading more closely, I see you've tried renaming it.  That should work, as I mentioned above.  What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: The issue was something in the content, the way I imported the .csv file into the database cause something. I imported the rows a few at a time - and somehow made my way thru all 600 rows with no error. DB complete... and it worked in the app. weird. probably an encoding issue with the content or .csv itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you open sqlite3 database with `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` you create the database if it does not exists ([Documentation of sqlite3_open](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_open)). You can dump database from CLI by `dump` command.